# Symfony 2 & FOSUserBundle : authenticate user after resetting password

Tags: authentication, symfony, fosuserbundle

When overriding FOSUserBundle resetting password controller, there is a function call to "authenticateUser" method (line 104) :

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/ResettingController.php#L104

```
....
$this->authenticateUser($user);
....
```

My problem is that I already override the Symfony authentication handler, and have my own logic when a user logs in.

**EDIT**
Here is my authentication handler :

```
<?php

/* ... all includes ... */

class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    private $router;
    private $container;

    public function __construct(Router $router, ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        // retrieve user and session id
        $user = $token->getUser();

        /* ... here I do things in database when logging in, and dont want to write it again and again ... */

        // prepare redirection URL
        if($targetPath = $request->getSession()->get('_security.target_path')) {
            $url = $targetPath;
        }
        else {
            $url = $this->router->generate('my_route');
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

}
```

So, How could I call the "onAuthenticationSuccess" method from my authentication handler in the ResettingController ?
In order to avoid rewriting the same code...

Thanks for your help !

Aurel

Comment: could you post your custom auth handler?

Comment: see my edit in my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call your onAuthenticationSuccess method loading it as a service. In your config.yml:

```
authentication_handler:
    class: Acme\Bundle\Service\AuthenticationHandler
    arguments:
        container: "@service_container"
```

And then, call it in the authenticateUser function:

```
protected function authenticateUser(UserInterface $user) {
      try {
        $this->container->get('fos_user.user_checker')->checkPostAuth($user);
      } catch (AccountStatusException $e) {
          // Don't authenticate locked, disabled or expired users
          return;
      }

      $providerKey = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');
      $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
      $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
      $request = $this->container->get('request');
      $this->container->get('authentication_handler')->onAuthenticationSuccess($request, $token);
}
```

this do the trick and pass through your custom auth handler. [More info](http://blog.logicexception.com/2011/10/symfony2-securitybundle-and.html).